# Correct notation for inverse normal (Z)?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

In my maths lesson today, my teacher said the inverse normal of $Z$ cannot be written as $Z^{-1}$.

Is this the correct notation?

Comment: What is "inverse norm of Z"? Do you mean inverse cumulative distribution of normal distribution? What is Z?

Comment: Z is the standardised normal, where mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1. And yeah I guess I mean that, my question is:
Is Z^-1 a correct notation?

Comment: Please edit your question. "Norm" in mathematics has it's own meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) it does *not* mean "normal distribution"!

Comment: $z^{-1}$ could mean reciprocal and could mean inverse (namely, inverse function). Whenever $z$ means standardised value I would expect $z^{-1}$ to mean reciprocal rather than inverse, but equally in practice it's not a quantity that seems to arise. Consider that if $z = 0$, then it's indeterminate. I am with those who prefer to speak of quantile functions any way (to the extent possible!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use symbol $F$ for a cumulative distribution function, then $F^{-1}$ is its inverse (or quantile function). It is a standard notation for an [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of any function in mathematics. So

$$ \Pr(Z \le z) = F(z) = p$$

and

$$ z = F^{-1}(p) $$

So it is not inverse of random variable $Z$, but inverse of its cumulative distribution function. Of course, if you want to use $Z$ symbol to denote cumulative distribution function, then the notation is perfectly fine. No one said we need to always use $F$ for it!

Comment: I'm in the UK and our exam board says the standardised normal uses a random variable Z, not F :/

Comment: I can't say for them, but I guess that what is meant is that there is some random variable Z that follows distribution F. I would suggest reading your notes or other materials carefully to read the definitions of the notation that was used.

Comment: In Britain we also use $F$ for cumulative distribution function. The exam board referred to is presumably for high (secondary) school examinations. If the usage is different at introductory level, then I am surprised, but that need not sway discussions.

Comment: The Greek letter phi is used for the normal density and capital phi for the cumulative normal.  Use phi in place of F in Tim's answer.

Comment: @Michael That comment misses the point of Tim's answer.  (Mathematician) Lewis Carroll made it in a memorable passage in *Through the Looking Glass*: 'The question is,' said Alice, 'whether you can make [mathematical symbols] mean so many different things.' 'The question is,' said Humpty Dumpty, 'which is to be master — that's all.'

Comment: @whuber That is a nice joke.  I prefer Alice in Wonderland where we can play croquet.

Comment: @Michael It's no joke.  Mathematics (and even statistics) is sufficiently rich and complex that we cannot afford to dedicate common symbols like "$\phi$" and "$\Phi$" to single concepts.  For instance, many statistics texts and papers even co-opt the well-known symbol "$\pi$" to refer to probabilities rather than the area of a unit circle.  Although having conventions, such as trying to use the same symbols for the same concepts within a narrow body of work, can be helpful, it is *essential* that writers have control over the meanings of the symbols they use.

Comment: We are on the same page so don't worry.  I want to go to the Mad Hatter's tea party. So I prefer Alice in Wonderland.  Wouldn't you want to go too Bill?